# Can't access wiki site through any other computers on my LAN

Tags: apache-http-server, php, wamp, mediawiki

I am trying to set up an internal wiki site for my company. Product info, specs that sort of thing. I have downloaded and installed WAMP Server 2.2 (Apache 2.2.22 MySQL 5.5.24 PHP 5.3.13) as well as the newest version of the mediawiki software on my Windows XP SP3 machine. Installation went fine. I now have the directory c:\wamp\www\fpswiki and i can access the wiki site through:

```
http://localhost/fpswiki

http://computername/fpswiki

http://computerip/fpswiki
```

but only from the server machine on which WAMP Server and Mediawiki are installed.

I have the firewall off and port 80 open (redundant i think) on both the server and the computer I'm using to test.

I have also tried changing the allow statements in the apache configuration file httpd.conf. I have tried:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and,

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.0
</Directory>
```

Neither of which worked. On the test computer I don't get an error message, just "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" and a Diagnose button that does nothing useful when pressed.

What I can see from the test computer are .php files in the www folder. I can also get to the WAMP Server splash screen through the browser on the test computer by typing in the server computer name or ip. Most interestingly (I think anyway) is that I can get all the info from the wiki page in an unformatted style by going to:

```
http://computername etc../fpswiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

it just pops up in the browser.

Ive been reading about this for 3 days and have also gotten this far using XAMPP and EasyPHP. My WAMP Server is in online mode and the icon is green.

I have no need to broadcast this to the outside internet. I only want it to be accessible to computers on our network as it will be used for internal employee reference only.

Comment: Please don't post on multiple sites http://serverfault.com/questions/515835/cant-access-mediawiki-site-from-other-computers-on-my-network  A moderator or reviewers will quickly flag to move if the question is on the wrong site.

Comment: I think we solved this on wampserver.com already. Use Allow from 192.168.0 to allow any ip in the 192.168.0 subnet.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm having essentially this same problem, but I'd additionally like to allow outside internet traffic only so I can get to it from a variety of workplaces. Is there a similar solution that you know of? I don't see an answer here, and the other linked question has been deleted.

Comment: @tmpearce Try `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all` This will allow access from anywhere, local or remote.

Comment: What about file permissions on the wiki install? That is one that has been a problem for me in the past. A recursive `chown` or `chmod` might be in order. I'd add this as just a comment, but I'm not allowed yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since the question was made, but this worked for me, the problem is in the wiki config side no in the apache config side,
In the LocalSettings.php file in the MediaWiki folder locate these lines:

```
## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
## Change from local to servername:<port>
$wgServer = "http://localhost";
```

change this "http://localhost" to $wgServer = "http://computername:81";

in my case I am using the 81 port

No need to restart the services just reload the Wiki page.